# Field length in geopandas shapefile output

Tags: python, shapefile, geopandas

I am converting an excel sheet to .shp via pandas i.e. I have a dataframe with 150+ columns and ~900 records (increasing by about 50 every day), that I convert to geodataframe and export to shp:

`output_data.to_file('myfilename.shp', driver='ESRI Shapefile')`

Saving this data to shp in Global Mapper creates a 3.5MB dbf

In QGIS, a 14MB dbf

Using Geopandas 6.5MB dbf

I've seen that the geodataframe has 15 decimal places for every numeric field, including whole numbers. Same thing for QGIS. Global Mapper's field lengths are equal to the lengthiest field in each column.

How can I keep geopandas from adding 15 decimals? I assume this is what bloats the filesize since I refactored some fields in QGIS and got a much smaller output dbf. The fields are also shorter in pandas df, before converting to geodf.

**Edit:**
Couldn't find a way to use GDAL RESIZE before saving as shp.. What I ended up doing:

export to shp using geopandas

`output_data.to_file('myfilename.shp', driver='ESRI Shapefile')`

resize using gdal/ogr

`dbf = ogr.Open('myfilename.shp', 1)`

`dbf.ExecuteSQL('RESIZE myfilename', dialect='sqlite')`

This took a 47MB dbf down to 27MB, however only shortened string fields.

Comment: [4 Methods to Round Values in Pandas DataFrame](https://datatofish.com/round-values-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: You may need to use some of the `fiona` options to specify a precision in the output shapefile. See https://fiona.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#writing-vector-data Does it have to be a shapefile? Can you save to a GeoPackage?

Comment: thanks @gene I have tried that, but as soon as the df is written to dbf the trailing digits reappear

Comment: thanks @Spacedman unfortunately it has to be a shapefile. The only specification that I can see is defining a schema by passing a dict, which dictates the data types but not the length. Unless I'm missing something?

Comment: Section 1.6.2 shows how to set data type and length, eg "float:15.2" is a floating point number with two decimals points. What does `ogrinfo` show for the formats for your various shapefiles?

Comment: Probably quite large lengths are used by default if they are not explicitly set. As a comparison see the GDAL documentation https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/shapefile.html. GDAL also offers a special SQL function RESIZE.

Comment: @Spacedman `ogrinfo` shows max field lengths all around, 80 for strings and 24:15 for all numeric. I'm using custom schemas now in a related project. However I'd like to use GDAL resize as @user30184 suggests. Any idea how/where to pass arguments to GDAL? I'm assuming it's in `to_file()` but not sure of the formatting etc.

Comment: If you can modify the driver maybe you should consider trying other format than shp. Otherwise you can consider modifying the type of every numeric column of your gdf

Answer (score 0):

geopandas uses fiona to save shp. You can use schema to define field length and precision. Or to preserve same schema as input shp.
More info:

https://fiona.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#format-drivers-crs-bounds-and-schema

```
input_gdf = gpd.read_file(shp_path)
# original schema
with fiona.open(shp_path) as src:
    # Extract the schema
    schema = src.schema

# perform your stuff

input_gdf.to_file('res_path', schema=schema)
```